# Joomla site shows IP address instead of url

Tags: joomla3.0

I am finalizing my Joomla-site with a Siteground host and encounter the following problem: my site shows the IP-adress instead of the url. Although I type in the url (www.nooitmeerfile.be by the way), it shows the IP-adress.

Could someone please give me a step-by-step explanation on how to fix this? I happen to find a lot of fragmented answers cluttered around the web. I am a novice user, and I'm stuck :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible steps to debug your issue:

- Check configuration.php `public $live_site = '';` and try to add your
  domain (without trailing slash).
- Check if `.htaccess` file is not altered and try to [download](http://www.joomla.org/download.html) and use a fresh copy.
- Check if you are using 3rd party sef components / plugins and try to disable them.
- Clear your joomla and browser cache.
- Contact your hosting provider if something in your hosting is misconfigured.

Hope this helps